# Equivalence of Visualforce/HTML "title" attribute for mouseover text in aura datatable component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, accessibilty

I have my Aura (yes, I know it's not as cool as LWC) component displaying a datatable. It works great, but I want to have the full text of the field show when I hover over a cell. I can do this in Visualforce using Lightning Design System

```
<th class="" scope="col">
  <div class="slds-truncate" title="Amount">Amount</div>
</th>
```

and setting the title to whatever I want.

How do I do this with my lightning datatable?

I'm not sharing my code because I'm using the code in the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation and in https://github.com/AliakseiSasnouski/RelatedList/blob/master/aura/RelatedList/RelatedListController.js and I want my text column to show the full value when I hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible. As per the "Formatting with Data Types" section on the [official Aura documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation), the only base components that support the `tooltip` attribute is the `url` type, which uses the `lightning:formattedUrl` base component. And the only base component that supports the `title` attribute are the buttons base components (`lightning:button` and `lightning:buttonIcon`).

That's not to say that it is impossible to have the title attribute available... if you have the skills, you can create your own data table component following the guidelines in the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#site-main-content).